# Altering an ASP.Net jquery to reusable/generic function

Tags: html, jquery, .net

I have a .net form with multiple div sections. I have a button which toggles the visibility for each of them. Currently I have only managed to get it working with one block of jquery for each btn/div.

1. Could I please get some assistance in making a single jquery code block that can be reused for **n** `div` sections?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSection1").click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Show") {
                $("#Section1").show();
                $(this).val("Hide");
            } else {
                $("#Section1").hide();
                $(this).val("Show");
            }
        });
    </script>

    <input id="btnSection1" value="Show" runat="server" type="button" name="btnSection1"/>
    <div id="Section1" style="display: none;">
        Section 1 text
    </div>
```

2. Any advice in converting the jquery from using `val` to `text` so as to use `asp:Button` rather than `<input' type="button" />`? The following does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function () {
    $("#btnSection1").click(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "Show") {
            $("#Section1").show();
            $(this).text("Hide");
        } else {
            $("#Section1").hide();
            $(this).text("Show");
        }
    });
</script>


<asp:Button ID="btnSection1" runat="server" Text="Show" name="btnSection1"/>
<div id="Section1" style="display: none;">
    Section 1 text
</div>
```

Cheers in Advance.

Comment: Can you please check on your console if there's any errors printed? Please also change ID to use small id like `id="btnSection1"`. Most importantly, check for errors on console, they'll have some leads in terms of why it isn't working.

Comment: cheers however no errors in console and altering to lowercase did not make an impact.